# unable to find main in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, compiler-errors

Here is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Range {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
 System.out.println("Greetings.");

 int min,max;

 System.out.println("Enter a minimum and maximum value.");
 Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
 min = keyboard.nextInt();
 max = keyboard.nextInt();
 System.out.println("The number of values  in the range from " + min + "to " + max + " is");
 for (int i = min; i <= max; i++){
 System.out.println(i); 
}


}
}
```

Exception:

```
run:
Error: Could not find or load main class project.Project
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)
```

could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: This is not a compile error. You're telling Netbeans to **run** the `project.Project` class, and this class doesn't exist. The error has nothing to do with the code you posted. What I just told is what the error message says. Read error messages carefully: they have a meaning, and tell you what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a *compiler* error - that's when you're trying to *run* the code.

And the answer is simple - you're trying to run `project.Project`, but your class is actually just `Range` (in the default package, by the looks of it).

Comment: so how do i fix it? i just started java and i cant figure out how to do get it to run

Comment: @user2534145: Well I'm not a Netbeans user, but somewhere you must be able to specify the class to run - you want to run the `Range` class. From Malcolm's answer, it sounds like it's in project properties.

Answer (score 1):

You are told that Java Runtime can't find the main class to run the app, and it looks like it's set to `project.Project` whereas it should be set to `Range` since that's the full name of the class containing your main method.

Right click the project, select **Properties**, then go to the **Run** tab. Then set *Main Class* to `Range`. Assuming you're launching the correct project, you'll be fine. If not, then check if it is set as main project (right click it and select the corresponding menu item) or right click it and select **Run** to launch it.

Answer (score 0):

**Set your main project**. This is not a compile error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn using NetBeans, the different steps to write, compile and run the programs. Once you know all this such errors will never bug you. Here is the tutorial to help you with that:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/netbeans.html